# Transferring magento to MediaTemple

Tags: apache, magento, mediatemple

After transferring a Magento installation using [these instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server), when I try to browse to the home page I am redirected to the "downloader" page ie http://mysite.com/downloader  and then I get a blank page.  Any ideas where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic `.htaccess` issue. Are you sure your `.htaccess` came over correctly from the old server and any relevant changes made?